# Alternative way to perform iteration instead of for-loop

Tags: python, loops

I have performing an iteration as shown below

```
def func(x_0, maxiter):           # iteration function
    
    x_i = x_0      #initial x value for interation
    
    for i in range(maxiter):
        
        x_f = x_i + (x_i)**2 - np.log(x_i)   #random mathematical function I want to iterate  
        x_i = x_f                        

    return x_i
```

I want to perform the iteration without a maximum iteration value `maxiter` and instead want the iteration to be done until a condition is met such as `abs(x_f - x_i) < 0.01`. What other alternative approach is there.

Note: This is a dummy code with a random mathematical function.

Comment: The python standard lists all available control constructs.  Read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a while loop is what you're looking for

```
def func(x_0):           # iteration function
    
    x_i = x_0      #initial x value for interation
    diff = True
    
    while diff:
        x_f = x_i + (x_i)**2 - np.log(x_i)   #random mathematical function I want to iterate 
        diff = abs(x_f - x_i) > 0.01
        x_i = x_f                        

    return x_i
```